# Return an Array of values of First <td> in Each <tr> of <tbody>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am trying to return an array of values for the first `<td>` of every `<tr>` within `<tbody>` of my table.

A **demo** here (attempt, not working) http://jsfiddle.net/vJqeT/1/

My JS Code:

```
var newArray = $('#table1 tr:first td').map(function() {
    return $(this).html();
});
```

My expected result in my demo is:

> [A, 1]

Comment: var newArray = $('#table1 tr td:first-child').map(function() {
        return $(this).html();
    });

Comment: If you want "every `<tr>`", why are you specifying `tr:first` in your selector?

Comment: I guess that is why I am asking a question here :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

target all TR's, and then all TD's that are the first child of a TR, then get the trimmed text :

```
var newArray = $.map($('#table1 tr td:first-child'), function (el) {
    return $.trim( $(el).text() );
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vJqeT/6/)

Comment: @Jack so, you changed the OP's markup in order to break this solution? Why, exactly?

Comment: @Jack - when posting an answer I tend to concentrate on the actual given code. If I change the code in the question I can make pretty much anything work or fail, but it's not very relevant. I do however agree that if you nest elements inside the table this would have issues, but that is easily solved with `$('#table1 > tr ....` but adding that just in case there's a nested table when there is no such thing in the question makes no sense.

Comment: The question is somewhat ambiguous, which is the reason I've added it. First td of every tr within tbody could mean "of every tr child of tbody" or "of every tr descending from tbody". It's not meant as critique :)

Answer (score 1):

A few things ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/dDvGL/1)):

1. You've targeted `tr:first` so any subsequent rows are ignored.
2. You should be targeting *cells* rather than *rows*.
3. jQuery's [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector is easily confused with [`:first-child`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3afirst-child). Unfortunately, `:first` returns only one item. Use `:first-child` instead.

   - or [`:first-of-type`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3afirst-of-type) if you're expecting mixed `td`/`th` within the same row.
4. Call [`toArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/) so you get a plain array.

```
var newArray = $('#table1 td:first-child span').map(function () {
    return $(this).html();
}).toArray();

console.log(newArray);
```